# Ways to give a SQLite a variable name

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am tracking changes made to a levels in a game. The way I currently track changes is in a sqlite database. Each level is supposed to have its own database, as just one database for all the levels would provide complications when adding and deleting levels. So for each level, I want a database that has the same name as that level. SO that changes made to level "foo" get written to database "foo". I don't need to edit the tables just the actual name of the database. I guess now that I could just use a file renaming function in python, but I would like to know if there is any way to change names from the start.
Heres an example:

```
    connection = sqlite.connect('\database\foo.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Where foo is the variable

Comment: Are you asking how to provide a name when opening the database?  Are you asking about the name provided when you connect?

Comment: I'm asking how to provide a variable name when creating a database.

Comment: "I guess now that I could just use a file renaming".  SQLite databases are just a file.  Why wouldn't you do this?

Comment: I thought there might be some kind of way to do it when creating the database

Comment: Why would you not just use the right name for the database file in the original connect? (You can't rename a database file while SQLite has it open, or at least not without having everything break. But if nothing has the file open, it's just a regular file of binary data.)

Comment: Because there isn't a definate "name" for the file when I connect. Depending on the level its tracking changes from, the name could need to be "castle" or "grass". I can't store changes from multiple levels in one file

Comment: [rant]"""Each level is supposed to have its own database, as just one database for all the levels would provide complications when adding and deleting levels.""" => "WRONG WAY. GO BACK." Where are you going to keep the info about relationships between levels, if not in a database? In a text file? Cunningly devised filenames for the SQLite databases? A Postit(TM) note? [/rant]

Comment: The levels don't have relationships.. The list of levels is handled by another part of the program. None of the data will need to be connected. Just the changes made in a single level need to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post some code for us to answer this completely.

You can use the [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) command to rename the tables within your database, you can rename your sqlite db file on disk if you close it first, and you can use a variable in your python code to represent the name of the DB you're using. But you need to be more specific if you want a more specific answer.